# PPPD Connect script failed

Tags: raspberry-pi, uart, at-command, ppp, pppd

I'm using the Raspberry Pi 4 and trying to have an Internet access using the A9G GSM/GPRS+GPS Module.

1. At first I have install `ppp` with `sudo apt-get install ppp screen elinks`
2. I have create a file with name `rnet` in path `/etc/ppp/peers/rnet`:

```ini
# My APN internet.vodafone.gr
connect "/usr/sbin/chat -v -f /etc/chatscripts/gprs -T internet.vodafone.gr"

# Communication port:
/dev/ttyS0

# Baudrate
9600

# Assumes that your IP address is allocated dynamically by the ISP.
noipdefault

# Try to get the name server addresses from the ISP.
usepeerdns

# Use this connection as the default route to the internet.
defaultroute

# Makes PPPD "dial again" when the connection is lost.
persist

# Do not ask the remote to authenticate.
noauth

# No hardware flow control on the serial link with GSM Modem
nocrtscts

# No modem control lines with GSM Modem
local
```

3. In file `gprs` in path `/etc/chatscripts/gprs` I have add the line that need my **"MY_4_DIGIT_PIN"**:

```ini
ABORT           BUSY
ABORT           VOICE
ABORT           "NO CARRIER"
ABORT           "NO DIALTONE"
ABORT           "NO DIAL TONE"
ABORT           "NO ANSWER"
ABORT           "DELAYED"
ABORT           "ERROR"

# cease if the modem is not attached to the network yet
ABORT           "+CGATT: 0"

""              AT
TIMEOUT         12
OK              ATH
OK              ATE1

# +CPIN provides the SIM card PIN
OK              AT+CPIN="MY_4_DIGIT_PIN"

# +CFUN may allow to configure the handset to limit operations to
# GPRS/EDGE/UMTS/etc to save power, but the arguments are not standard
# except for 1 which means "full functionality".
#OK             AT+CFUN=1

OK              AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","\T","",0,0
OK              ATD*99#
TIMEOUT         22
CONNECT         ""
```

So when I'am trying to starts up the `rnet` file:

```sh
sudo pon rnet
```

I get this error message in syslog (`cat /var/log/syslog | grep pppd`):

```auto
Oct 14 18:14:22 raspberrypi pppd[3063]: pppd 2.4.7 started by pi, uid 0
Oct 14 18:14:35 raspberrypi pppd[3063]: Connect script failed
Oct 14 18:15:06 raspberrypi pppd[3063]: Connect script failed
Oct 14 18:15:37 raspberrypi pppd[3063]: Connect script failed
...
```

When I am trying to run the below AT commands, the module seems to be work fine and be able to connected to network:

```auto
AT
OK

AT+CPIN?
+CPIN:READY
OK

AT+CREG?
+CREG: 1,1

OK
AT+CGATT?
+CGATT:1
OK

AT+COPS?
+COPS: 0,2,"20205"

AT+CGACT?
+CGACT: 1, 1

AT+HTTPGET="http://www.example.com/"
OK
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
...
```

So I can't understand if I have have writing something wrong in file `rnet` or is something else that I am not doing it right. If you have any idea please help me.

Comment: The problem have solved soon i will upload the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that my A9G Module, was not getting enough power.
Therefore, check if your A9G Module is turned on, before starting the process
and make sure that you have disabled login shell to be accessible over serial,
and also you have enabled the serial interface.